# Conflicts in svn

Tags: svn

What's the correct procedure to merge a branch to trunk in svn in command line?
Currently I just commit at branch, then switch working copy to the trunk, and merge the brwhen merging branch to trunkanch to working copy, at last, commit the changes to trunk.
While I am merging the branch to working copy at trunk, there are always conflicts I have to edit myself.
This seem to be annoying. Is the procedure correct? Could I avoid the conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

Ya, conflicts are part of the process, there are some graphical tools out there that will help you resolve these conflicts.  However if you need to do it command line, there is a good tutorial here: http://www.duchnik.com/tutorials/vc/svn-conflicts

Its really quite simple actually, once you understand the basics of what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

Conflicts surface whenever the differencing logic can not make an educated assumption on the expected behavior during the merge. Instead of fouling up the merge it forces the decision to the user and allows them to make an educated decision to force the desired outcome.

A walk through for what you describe can be found [here](http://www.sepcot.com/blog/2007/04/SVN-Merge-Branch-Trunk). Keep in mind however that conflicts are inevitable and can not be avoided.